# Show menu until user input meets condition

Tags: python

I want to repeatedly ask the user for input (choosing a menu option), until they choose a valid option.

My main menu is:

```
print ("Please choose whether you would like to encrypt a message, decrypt a message or exit the program.")
userSelection = input("Please type E for encrypt message\n D for decrypt message or\n X to exit the program.")
```

If they do not input `E`, `D` or `X`, I want this menu to appear again and the program to restart.

So far I have:

```
while True:
    userSelection != "E" or userSelection !=  "e" or userSelection != "D" or userSelection != "d" or userSelection != "X" or userSelection != "x"
    print ("Please choose an option from the menu.")
    break
```

How would I get it to return?

Comment: I have edited your question, specifically: code blocks should be indented by 4 spaces for proper highlighting and inline code should be between backticks. I've also added a problem statement and reworded the question title. You can further improve your question by adding what happens with your program as it is, and what you expect to happen instead, or how you're stuck specifically.

Comment: I've also removed the "encryption" tag, as the question is not really about encryption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `while` loop!

```
userSelectionOptions = ['e', 'd', 'x']
print ("Please choose an option from the menu.")
user_input = ''
user_input = input("Please type E for encrypt message\n D for decrypt message or\n X to exit the program: \n")
while user_input.lower() not in userSelectionOptions:
    print ("Please choose an option from the menu.")
    user_input = input("Please type E for encrypt message\n D for decrypt message or\n X to exit the program: \n")

# do stuff with the input
```

With this code, you ask the user for input first, and try to validate it. If the validation fails, the user goes into the while loop until the input they give is valid.

NOTE: edited to include your input code. Remember if you are running python2.7 you need to use `raw_input`.